# Pass an arbitrary value (such as an image width) with BuildDisplay to an alternate

Tags: c#, razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

We want to share the following logic among our Orchard views.

```
@helper CreateImgFromMediaPart(dynamic mediaPart, int width = 150)
{
    var imgSrc = mediaPart != null ? mediaPart.MediaUrl : string.Empty;
    var imgAlt = mediaPart != null ? mediaPart.AlternateText : string.Empty;
    <img alt="@imgAlt" src="@imgSrc" />
}
```

Toward that goal, we created an alternate called `Media-Image.SizedThumbnail.cshtml` that renders the `Media_Image` shape.

**Media-Image.SizedThumbnail.cshtml** - create a shared alternate

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.MediaLibrary.Models
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions
@model dynamic

    @{
        ContentItem contentItem = Model.ContentItem;
        var media = contentItem.As<MediaPart>();
        var image = contentItem.As<ImagePart>();
        var width = media.Width != null ? media.Width : 200; // get the width
    }

    <div>
        <img src="@Display.ResizeMediaUrl(
                       Width: width, 
                       Mode: "max", 
                       Alignment: "middlecenter", 
                       Path: media.MediaUrl)" />
    </div>
```

We can successfully call that alternate with `Display(BuildDisplay(mediaPart, "ResizeThumbnail))`. It almost works. The challenge is to pass the `Width` that we want the image to become.

**MyView.cshtml** - Try to pass the Width.

```
// Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
// 'Orchard.MediaLibrary.Models.MediaPart' does not contain a definition for 'Width'
// This is odd to me, because mediaPart is dynamic
mediaPart.Width = 200;
@Display(BuildDisplay(mediaPart, "SizedThumbnail")

// Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 
// The best overloaded method match for
// BuildDisplay(Orchard.ContentManagement.IContent, string, string)' 
// has some invalid arguments
var mediaPartExpando = MyFunctions.ToDynamic(mediaPart);
mediaPartExpando.Width = 200;
@Display(BuildDisplay(mediaPartExpando, "SizedThumbnail")

// System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
var mediaPartExpando = MyFunctions.ToDynamic(mediaPart);
mediaPartExpando.Width = 200;
var mediaPartAgain = mediaPartExpando as IContent;
@Display(BuildDisplay(mediaPartAgain, "SizedThumbnail")
```

I am clearly battling with the compiling and runtime. How can we pass a width through BuildDisplay to an alternate?

Comment: Just commenting on the obvious: `'Orchard.MediaLibrary.Models.MediaPart' does not contain a definition for 'Width'` seems to indicate that your model doesn't have a property named `Width`...

Comment: It's `dynamic`. I will update the example to show that.

Comment: Right you are... I did not look close enough. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's not great that you would call BuildDisplay from a view. It would be better, if possible, if the driver or controller that is responsible for creating this MyView.cshtml did that.

Secondly, what BuildDisplay returns is a shape, to which you can add properties dynamically. So you should be able to do this:

```
@Display(BuildDisplay(mediaPart, "SizedThumbnail").Width(200))
```

Comment: In the questions scenario, it isn't possible to modify the driver, because the view is in a theme, and because the view is for a query's shape layout. In this case, does calling BuildDisplay seem a reasonable option?

Comment: Well, the problem is that BuildDisplay will potentially query the database, and cause issues. It should be avoided from the view, it's just unclean. It isn't always easy to do so, however. One often overlooked possibility is to have more than one driver for the same part, or to manipulate a shape from a shape table provider.

Comment: It's good to know how to shoot myself in the foot with `BuildDisplay` during times when that sacrifice is the only option. The Orchard.MediaLibrary module, for instance, uses `BuildDisplay` in a view five times.

Comment: As I said, it *should* be avoided. Looking at the examples you pointed to, one is in an edit view, and the others should, in my opinion, be refactored so that the work is done in the driver or in a lazy field.

Comment: Good to know. I'm refactoring my own code today to eliminate `BuildDisplay` calls.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag` will do until we find a better answer:

MyView.cshtml - Try to pass the Width.

```
 ViewBag.ResizedThumbnailWidth = 200;
 @Display(BuildDisplay(mediaPart, "SizedThumbnail"))
```

Media-Image.SizedThumbnail.cshtml - Shared alternate

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.MediaLibrary.Models
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions
@model dynamic

    @{
        ContentItem contentItem = Model.ContentItem;
        var media = contentItem.As<MediaPart>();
        var image = contentItem.As<ImagePart>();
        var width = ViewBag.ResizedThumbnailWidth ?? 200;
    }

    <div>
        <img src="@Display.ResizeMediaUrl(
                       Width: width, 
                       Mode: "max", 
                       Alignment: "middlecenter", 
                       Path: media.MediaUrl)" />
    </div>
```